# What is the use of shift method in Selenium Webdriver

Tags: ruby, arrays, selenium

I'm quite new to Ruby so I'm probably messing up somewhere but here it is.

I'm using Selenium::Webdriver in the below code the driver object = @br.

```
@hists = @br.find_elements(:xpath => "/html/body/center/form[1]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody")
@hists.shift
@hists.each do |x|
  puts x.text
end
```

This throws the `NoMethodExcepetion 'text'` because it thinks `@hists` is a blank array and not an array Element objects. Now, if I remove `@hists.shift` this prints out each elements text just fine.

Why is `.shift` doing this?

Also, I need to do more processing on this info later on in another class, and the data gets lost in the shuffle.

Ideas?

Edit****

I tried using just x and it didn't through any exceptions, but it didn't print anything either.

Edit*******
Didn't print anything either. I feel like @br.find_elements is passing the whole array of elements found into @hists[0] as I checked the value of @hists.shift is returning the whole array. I'm going to re-factor and manually add the values I'm looking for into each element of the array. I'll post it if it works.

Thanks!

Comment: I think your conclusion is wrong - if `@hists` was a blank array, no exception would have occurred, since `[].each do |x| puts x.text end` works - it simply does not enter the loop. Could you change `puts x.text` to `puts x`?

Comment: I tried using just 'code'puts x'code' and it didn't throw the exception, but it didn't print anything.